# MongoDB index selection based on index stats

Tags: mongodb, indexing

we have a collection with almost 300M documents. I'm working on improving a query performance by adding index on that. 
Consider following is the doc structure:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("abc1323",
a:"val1", 
b: "val2", 
c: { "f1" : "v1",
     "f2" : "v2",
     "f3" : "v3"
   }
d: "val3"
}
```

and query being executed like:

db.collection.find({
_id:  {'$gte': {ObjectId('5de06d900000000000000000')}, '$lt': {ObjectId('5de0de100000000000000000')}},
c.f3: "v3" 
})

Indexes I have created are:
Index1: `{"_id" : 1, "c.f3" : 1}`
Index2: `{"c.f3" : 1, "_id" : 1}`

With index1, execution stats are (winning plan)

```
"executionStats" : {
                "nReturned" : 59,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 7,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 850,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 59,
```

while with Index2,  execution stats are:

```
"executionStats" : {
                "nReturned" : 59,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 305,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 59,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 59,
```

So for Index1, query returns results in fastest time, but `totalKeysExamined` are more that what it returned, while using Index2,  query takes some time to return result, but `totalKeysExamined` is exactly same with the `nReturned` i.e. scanned:returned ration is exactly 1, at the cost of executionTime. 
So I need some clarity on choosing between these two indexes. Index1 is faster but throughput(scanned:return ration) is poor , while Index2 gives excellent throughput. Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: I think **indexes are used for performance** - the speed. That is what **the application users want, a fast response time**. I can only suggest test with more of these queries with different ranges of data and note the query plan outputs. That said, how does the query perform if the index has the `{ "c.f3" : 1 }` key only - you may want to try and see..

Comment: Are you sure you are comparing the right way? index2 should be faster as the indexes are stored as b-tree. It will get to the branch with c.f3: v3 and then do a range. While you running your tests, make sure only one index exists at that time and there is no other operation going on.

Comment: @Yahya, Ideally that should be the case, and using Index2 should give better performance, but this is not what happening. Not sure why Index1 is faster in this case.

Comment: Query execution time will vary depending on factors like whether the index & documents are in memory as well as other operations that are executing concurrently. I would definitely choose the more efficient index. If you compare the full explain output you may find some differences that help clarify where the time was spent -- I suspect query #1 would be fetching less data from disk or yielding fewer times. For a fairer comparison you should also average execution time over multiple iterations.